# XNA C# - How to make a button pressed without being pressed

Tags: c#, button, xna, pressed

I've got a starting image which, when you press enter, it goes to the game. The problem is that since this is an image, the button has to be held down in order to stay showing the game screen. Is there a way to make it so that once you press the button, the image stays off?

```
Update Method:

helpScreen = new HelpScreen(this); 

if (!helpScreen.gamestarted && Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Enter))
{
    helpScreen.gamestarted = true;
}

Draw Method:

if (!helpScreen.gamestarted)
{
    helpScreen.Draw(spriteBatch);
}
```

Comment: you should really state in what programming language this is. Given the style != null, this should be c++/c - right?

Comment: Sorry, forgot that, its C# and done in XNA

Comment: okay, I am not a XNA guy, but it would be a better idea to not use "isKeyDown" to start your game (or better hide the help-screen to set the game visible?) but a "starting" screen (eg main) calling your game in some sort of forever() loop once you pressed enter and not "doing as if the key was pressed all the time". If you break that forever loop simply fall back to your main and give the user the possibility to start over

Comment: This is a small part of the code, at the moment, the help screen appears as an image, and then when you press enter it goes away to reveal the game thats running in the background, (I could have used gamestates, but it didn't work well), the problem is that you have to hold down the enter button whereas I want it to go once the button is pressed once.

Answer (score 0):

Store the state in your main game class:

```
private bool gameStarted = false;
```

In your update method check the input:

```
if (!gameStarted && Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Enter))
{
    gameStarted = true;
}
```

Later in your draw method only draw the start image, if the game has not been started yet:

```
if (!gameStarted)
{
    helpScreen.Draw(spriteBatch);
}
```

That way it will not be drawn again, once the player pressed the button. Also using a general `gameStarted` field clarifies your intentions and you can base other game logic on its state in a simple and natural way.

Comment: I've updated the game coding above to what you suggested. The Screen appears, and when you press enter the screen goes to the game, but it won't stay on the game unless you hold down enter - if you release enter, then it goes back to the help screen.

Comment: If you did exactly what I suggested and no code is interfering, it *has* to work. Just go through it line by line: When the application starts, *gameStarted is false*. The condition in the Draw method is met; the *helpscreen is drawn*. As soon as the user presses Enter, the condition in the update method is true and *gameStarted will be set to true*. The condition in the Draw method is now false and the *helpScreen will not be drawn* until gameStarted is set to false again.

Comment: Oh it worked! Thanks a ton.
I had to move helpScreen = new HelpScreen(this); to the LoadContent part instead of the update, and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Can I ask, have you done any other coding surrounding input? Or are you beginning with this help screen? Because this covers the very basics of input handling.

It seems like you are looking at this as an event driven system, when in fact it is a game loop. This means that you check a value each loop and base your output on that, rather than by events (eg. Click)

What I would do is record the previous value, then in the next loop, compare that value against the current value. Example in your Update method:

```
//Outside of Update loop declare
KeyboardState previousState = Keyboard.GetState();

//Inside update loop
if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyUp(Keys.Enter) && previousState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Enter))
{
        helpScreen = null;     }
```

This will trigger when the Enter button has been pressed and released. There are many other changes that I would perform on that code, but this should point you in the right direction for this particular problem.

Comment: I've started out with coding in XNA not long ago, and its for a piece of work. Everything about the game and the design is finished, and this helpscreen/startscreen is something that I wanted to add now, but wasn't really necessary. I would have done the different screens (i.e. game over, start screen, game screen) using public enum Gamestates, etc. But with the coding I have already, it was a big hassle to do and I've tried it 3 times with failure.

Comment: The helpScreen appears as you load up the game, and when you press enter, it removes itself to show the game, but the problem is that when enter is released, it goes back to the helpScreen instead of hiding the Helpscreen altogether. 

I understand that its not the right way to do it, but I am just trying to add something extra before handing it in.

Comment: Well then the method above should help you find the answer you seek.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I managed to get it to work by moving the helpScreen = new HelpScreen(this); into the LoadContent()